# Error attempting to load and run jmeter 3.3 script with java

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm attempting to run a jmeter script with java code.

I've followed the instructions, but when attempting to call SaveService.loadTree(file), I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'file path/file.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 31
version             : 3.3 r1808647
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the "ApacheJMeter_http" dependency was not in my pom.xml file. "ApacheJMeter_core" does not include all of the needed files for a basic test run.

Answer (score 0):

Your  `HTTPSamplerProxy` have an issue in definition. Follow [example](https://gist.github.com/uttesh/8ce5fde4ac5149b115f1):

```
            HTTPSamplerProxy examplecomSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
            examplecomSampler.setDomain("uttesh.com");
            examplecomSampler.setPort(80);
            examplecomSampler.setPath("/");
            examplecomSampler.setMethod("GET");
            examplecomSampler.setName("Open uttesh.com");
            examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
            examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
 ....
            HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
            threadGroupHashTree.add(examplecomSampler);
```